# Lord Acton's purported quote about "freedom faces four major challenges"

Tags: quotes, poetic

I read a Chinese article that quoted a passage purported to be from Lord Acton, describing how "**freedom faces four major challenges**", using google translation (from Chinese back to English) the quotes are like these,

> In each era, freedom faces four major challenges:
>
> The strong man's desire for concentration of power,
>
> The poor's resentment of unequal wealth,
>
> The ignorant's yearning for utopia,
>
> The unbelievers's confusion of freedom and indulgence.
>
> And their common root is radicalism

With the comment from @StuartF and the answer I got at [History SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66722/did-lord-acton-ever-say-freedom-faces-four-major-challenges)(Edwin Ashworth suggested me to ask the question there). I now believe Lord Acton did not say that. And my question was closed because it was off-topic at this SE. So I am changing it making it appropriate for this site and hope it can be reopened for answer.

I like the googled translated version (even though Lord Action did not say it). I think it speaks about the challenges freedom faces even in present day. But my English is not good enough to **make it more natural, more poetic**. Can someone help me to do that ?

Comment: Nearest I can find, which isn't very near, is "In every age its (i.e. liberty's) progress has been beset by its natural enemies, by ignorance and superstition, by lust of conquest and by love of ease, by the strong man’s craving for power, and the poor man’s craving for food." https://www.acton.org/research/history-freedom-antiquity That website has a lot of texts.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question; sourcing lengthy quotes is off-topic. This is perhaps one for History.SE, where there is a 'quotes' tag licensing _origin requests_.

Comment: I am voting to reopen this question because it poses a new and interesting problem: How to identify the original quotation when a text has been translated from English into a language like Chinese, which has a very different grammar, and then been translated programmatically back into English.

Comment: @StuartF I got an answer at History SE just as you commented. https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66722/did-lord-acton-ever-say-freedom-faces-four-major-challenges

Comment: Please delete. It is not correct to post questions on two SE sites, and you have the answer from _History_.

Comment: The solution: Copy the useful/interesting comments over to the other thread, then delete.

Comment: @GlobalCharm That might be a topic better suited to Meta ELU.

Comment: I don't get. What is this question asking? Why are you asking about a two level translation (automated) but not the original? Why would you whether the original is the same as a two step translation by asking if Acton "really said that". It's not an issue at that point. It's not a verbatim quote after it's been translated twice. It's just an exercise in judging a translation quality. Also, don't make us search around ourselves for the originals - quote those pieces and also give links to where you found them.... I'm at a loss... I just don't get it.

Comment: Clearly my original question and the fact that I left it here caused some problem so I edited it to make it more appreciate for this website (at least from my point of view).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I edited my question, would you agree it is appropriate for this website now? If you still don't think so please be kind to tell me how to edit it to make it appropriate for this site.

Comment: No. ELU looks at [less basic questions covering] the nuts and bolts of syntax, individual word choice, punctuation .... **Not** (a) who said what / (b) general writing / style advice.

Comment: Perhaps it would be more on-topic at https://writing.stackexchange.com/? I am not sure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Provenance of quotes is long -standingly -on-topic-. However, this particular quote was never likely to be found by simple appeal to the translation of the translation and no knowledge of Acton's work. [The question was answered very well over at History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66722/did-lord-acton-ever-say-freedom-faces-four-major-challenges) mostly because the original Chinese was given -and- the subject matter was presumably much better knowable there.

Comment: The Chinese translation was not a translation as far as I'm concerned - it was more of a paraphrase, reordering, and drawing different conclusions. So we (ELU) were given a problem to solve  that in fact had little to do with language. So there are many reasons not to bother with reopening this here on ELU. (a very interesting question, of course, just not appropriate for ELU).

Comment: @Mitch I did some further research about my question and found some interesting results. I update my question at History SE. Take a look if you are interested.

Comment: @Mitch You have a strange way of totalling votes. [Are 'Who first said ...?' questions on-topic?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2846/are-who-first-said-questions-on-topic/2847#2847)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nice find. Maybe I've convinced myself from my own answer. That being said, over the entire life of ELU, there are [numerous unclosed questions on the provenance of phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=who%20said%20first). So it is de facto on-topic.

Comment: @Mitch Now you've adjusted what you're saying. This is a lengthy quote, not a phrase. Your 'it' is disingenuous. // OP has now (a) posted on the correct site and (b) here  asked for a rewrite, proofreading/style advice. The question is unarguably in need of closing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth totally off-topic now. proofreading/writing advice